# Setting a python function name to a variable and trying to access its functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a project, and I'm getting the following error: `builtins.AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'intro_text'`
It's probably something stupid, as I'm still pretty new to python, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. 
The main function is as follows:

```
def play():
    world.load_tiles()
    player = Player()
    while player.is_alive() and not player.victory:
        room = world.tile_at(player.x, player.y)
        print(room.intro_text())
        room.modify_player(player)
        if player.is_alive() and not player.victory:
            choose_action(room, player)
        elif not player.is_alive():
            print("Your journey has come to an early end!")
```

The player class creates a new player object with an x and y location, hp, gold, and a victory boolean. The problem is occuring on the line with `print(room.intro_text())`. In the line before it we're calling world.tileat(), which looks like this:

```
def tile_at(x, y):
    if x < 0 or y < 0:
        return None
    try:

        return world_map[y][x]
    except IndexError:
        return None
```

This problem is arriving because I was having a hard time writing my own engine and decided to borrow some code from another project, and supplement it with my own. The x and y axis position stuff was really complicated, and I'm currently not at a sufficient skill level to write it on my own.

Just for reference, another method in the `world` file is `load_tiles()`, which looks like this:

```
def load_tiles():
    """Parses a file that describes the world space into the _world object"""
    with open('world/map.txt', 'r') as f:
        rows = f.readlines()
    x_max = len(rows[0].split('\t')) # Assumes all rows contain the same number of tabs
    for y in range(len(rows)):
        row = []
        cols = rows[y].split('\t')
        for x in range(x_max):
            tile_name = cols[x].replace('\n', '') 

            if tile_name == 'startTile':
                global start_tile_location
                start_tile_location = (x, y)    
                #print(start_tile_location)
            row.append(tile_name if tile_name else None)
        world_map.append(row)
```

`world_map` starts off as a blank list, and `start_tile_location` begins life as `None`.

The whole project is hosted [here](https://github.com/PwnKitteh/isms), if you want to really help me out and run it on your machine. It's meant to be run on linux, but it should work on windows. The only module it needs is random, as it creates its own classes for use.

Thank you, I'm really stuck here and appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: `room` will be a `tile_name` which is a string (or None). Where are defining the intro text for each room?

Comment: try to `print` only `room` what is there ? `print(room)`

Comment: @zimdero - room is the name of each room, as defined in the map.txt file. These names correspond to function names.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh - the intro text for each room is defined in the class for each room, as seen in the world.py file.